# Solr Data Import - Get InvalidConnectionAttributeException when importing from database

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to configure my Solr instance to import from the database.  So far, I've configured everything as described in the [Apache Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler), but consistently get this error:

```
 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server 
time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone.
You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone 
configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to 
utilize time zone support.
```

This is despite me enabling `SOLR_TIMEZONE="UTC"` in the init.d script and verifying that `-Duser.timezone=UTC` exists in the results for `ps auxww | grep solr`.

This is my DataImportHandler configuration:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type = "JdbcDataSource"
                driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url = "jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.141:3306/dev"
                user = "dev"
                password = "local_user" />
    <document>
        <entity name = 'id' query = "select * from index_document;" />
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

and it is visible in the Solr admin data import screen.  The odd thing about this is there are no dates in the db table I'm importing.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this was to alter the `url` to

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.141:3306/dev?serverTimezone=UTC"
```